# OTC framework generated code compilation fails due to an extra string "class " with a space

Tags: otcconverter, otcframework

Description:

1. Created an OTCS script file with a copy-source command to copy from source to target of GregorianCalendar type.
2. Executed a test project to generate the object conversion source code.
3. A word "class " prefixed to the 2nd parameter when OTC framework's DateCoverterFacade is invoked in the generated code.

   ```
    originDepRequest.setDate(DateConverterFacade.convert(date, class XMLGregorianCalendar.class));
   ```
4. Generated command from etc editor as below:

- copy:
  id: CP1
  from:
  objectPath: request.flightRequest.flightRequestOriginDestinationsCriteria.originDestCriteria[*].originDepCriteria.date
  to:
  objectPath: request.flightRequest.originDestRequest[*].originDepRequest.date
  factoryClassName: CP1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Create an issue for this on https://github.com/frank-a-otc/otcframework/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in version 2.7.0 and is pushed to maven central. Change dependency version in your project and try again.